# Pandas most efficient way to filter dataframe based on groupby mask

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to filter a dataframe based on the values in that df's `groupby` results on a column.  For example, if I have a dataframe with `columns := ticker, year, price`, I'd like to filter out of the df tickers whose first year is >= 1990.

or more technically where the ticker evaluates to True in `df.groupby('ticker').['year'].min() < 1990`

I am currently doing it this way:

```py
ticker_min_date_bool = df.groupby('ticker')['year'].min() < 1990 # get booleans
tickers_filt = [i for i in ticker_min_date_bool.index if ticker_min_date_bool[i]] # make list of tickers with criteria
df_new = df[df.ticker.isin(tickers_filt)] # filter df based on above list
```

However this feels a little clumsy to do in 3 lines and doesn't seem to scale well for larger datasets.

Are there any dataframe methods that accomplish this more efficiently?

Comment: dummy dataframe with expected output would help in providing a detailed solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do `transform`

```
ticker_min_date_bool = df.groupby('ticker')['year'].transform('min') < 1990
df_new = df[ticker_min_date_bool]
```

Or without `groupby`

```
s = df.loc[df['year']<1990,'ticker']
df_new = df[df['ticker'].isin(s)]
```

Comment: Perfect.  Now suppose I don't have a year column but a date column.  In my above example, I'm actually creating the min. year groupby with `df.groupby('ticker')['date'].apply(lambda x: x.dt.year.min() <= year_cutoff)`.  How can I accomplish your solution while also extracting the `dt.year` from the `date` column? `df.groupby('ticker')['year'].dt.year` doesn't work.  (That is, how do I do it with groupby, as I for me it's more syntactically legible)

Comment: @BrianBarry df['year'].dt.year.groupby(df['ticker']).transform('min')<1990